# Linux conect another Linux via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

My laptop's OS is Linux, and I want to connect my remote server, its OS is Linux CentOS. You know, on Windows, you can use Putty, XShell etc to connect remote Linux Machine. And I wonder if there are some softwares just like Putty or Xshell that can connect remote Linux Server.I know on Linux, you can use ftp to connect remote Linux Server's file system, but I want to use remote Linux Server's terminal to run some programs.

Comment: Just use the openssh client that is installed on every linux system. You can start it inside a terminal with `ssh`. The man page of the command (`man ssh`) explains in details how to use it. There are also ssh gui implementations under Linux, but they are not wide spread. The openssh CLI ssh command is powerful and much easier to use once you learned it.

Comment: If you know about SSH, why not use it ?

Comment: I use XShell on Windows to connect remote server. I haven't use ssh command before, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux you have SSH (openssh package usually or ssh-server or ssh) command `ssh`

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh user@remoteserver
```

**remoteserver** : This is the hostname or the ip address you need to connect to.

**user** : The username you use to connect to that system.

Upon successful connection you shall see the prompts to guide to further.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisngly, the tool you need is called `ssh`